# How do you export a .blend group

Tags: export

I've built a model in one project and want to import it into another. I see .blend files with groups that other people made. You click in the .group, get the item and you're all good to go. .. There don't seem to be any instructions anywhere on how to get it to make a group.. I don't want to export to unity or cad or anything like that - just simply move a model from one blender file to another. This must be possible. Any idea on the settings?

Comment: So you just want to move one object from one file to another?

Comment: what you need is either File > Link (Ctrl + Alt + O) or File > Append (Shift + F1).
with Link, you can import anything from A.blend to B.blend: objects, materials, etc. - but you can't edit the imports inside B.blend. however, any changes made inside A.blend to whatever was Linked, will propagate through the Link and reflect on B.blend.
Append is the opposite of that. you import a COPY which you can edit and there's no edit-propagation from A.blend to B.blend. hope this helps :]

Answer (score 1):

The ~.blend file you wish to import must first include a group, which you create in your original project file, by any of the normal means of creating a group: selecting the elements you want in the group, and selecting the menu item Object > Group > Make Group when the viewport is in object mode, or using the defined shortcut key for this, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>, or alternatively by using the "add to Group" options under the Group pane in the "object properties" tab of the properties editor. If a group is defined in the file you are wanting to append or link from, when you select the append or link option in the files menu, after selecting the file, you will see in the list of items you can append or link, a listing for "group". Select this, and select the desired group, just as you would another data type, e.g., object, mesh, or material.